# сравнение с регулярным выражением

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Скрипт получает переменную и сравнивает ее со значением, и при равенстве выполняет код
`else if(result === 'Сколько времени'){
        ...
}`

Проблема в том, что хочется как-то через регулярные выражение сделать, чтобы он сравнивал похожие варианты( сколько сейчас времени, какое время). Не работал с такими выражениями и не представляю как тут реализовать такое(можно конечно через кучу условий, но слишком много получится).

Comment: Из вашего вопроса не ясно главное: что вы с чем в результате хотите сравнивать. И когда этот результат у вас истиной должен быть, а когда ложью.

Comment: переменная result(например "сколько сейчас времени", "сколько времени", "какое сейчас время" т.е. что введет человек = какое-то выражение, которое будет улавливать это("...врем(я/ени)...")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такое выражение составил

```
"(подскажите\s+?){0,1}(сколько|какое|которое|который)(\s+?сейчас){0,1}\s+?(времени|время|час|часов)"
```

оно, конечно и неправильные с точки зрения чистого русского языка выражения пропускает, например `сколько сейчас час`. Но думаю это не является проблемой.

Тестируем тут - https://regex101.com/r/hkJw1k/1

код проверки может быть такой:

```js
var regex = /(подскажите\s+?){0,1}(сколько|какое|которое|который)(\s+?сейчас){0,1}\s+?(времени|время|час|часов)/;

function TestTimeRegex(str) {
  return str.search(regex) != -1;
}

console.log(TestTimeRegex("подскажите сколько сейчас времени"));
console.log(TestTimeRegex("трам пам время"));
```

В вашем случае

```
else if(TestTimeRegex(result)){
        ...
}
```

Comment: спасибо, а как сравнить именно с переменной result?

Comment: @СемёнШумилов добавил пример работы

Comment: спасибо, структуру понял кажется, вот только требует весь набор слов, буду разбираться)

Answer (score 1):

Я бы начал с того что завёл списочек всех вариантов, пока просто в текстовом виде, из него будет ясно как лучше запрограммировать такую систему.

Дело в том что если вариантов очень много, то писать регулярное выражение может быть сложное дело, а кроме того оно может выглядеть очень некрасиво.

Предлагаю создать некоторый массив атомарных регулярных выражений, и уже на основе массива через цикл сформировать результирующее регулярное выражение.

Можно даже просто сделать массив и просто в цикле саму проверку сделать, если есть одно совпадение, значит совпало. В любом случае красивее чем тупо подряд условия писать.

Comment: https://uiregex.com/ru на сайте сгенерировал регулярное выражение /^[а-я]{5,7} [а-я]{5,7}( [а-я]{7})?$/  но как с ним работать в моем примере?

Comment: @СемёнШумилов с ним никак, оно не подходит...

Comment: а как сравнение это лучше реализовать? переменной с элементами массива?